# How to send message to particular whatsapp contact programmatically using intent?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I searched various answers but all of them are outdated.
Whenever I tried using send to it only opens contact chooser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
     sendIntent.setComponent(new  ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
 sendIntent.putExtra("jid",     PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER")+"@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix

 startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**Update:**

The aforementioned hack cannot be used to add any particular message, so here is the new approach. Pass the user **mobile** in international format here without any brackets, dashes or plus sign. Example: *If the user is of India and his mobile number is **94xxxxxxxx** , then international format will be **9194xxxxxxxx**. Don't miss appending country code as a prefix in mobile number.*

```
  private fun sendMsg(mobile: String, msg: String){
    try {
        val packageManager = requireContext().packageManager
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val url =
            "https://wa.me/$mobile" + "?text=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, "utf-8")
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        i.data = Uri.parse(url)
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            requireContext().startActivity(i)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

> **Note**: This approach works only with contacts added in user's Whatsapp
> account.

Comment: is this still works?

Comment: can i have shell command for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the package name in the Intent like this

`intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");`

Full example:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);  
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just fire the below intent on the click on button:

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + mobile1);
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
       mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
       mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The text goes here");
       mIntent.putExtra("chat", true);
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, ""));
```

if number available on whatsapp then that particular user chat open and you send your message.If number not available on whatsapp the alert diaolge open in that case.

hope this help you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution

```
 private void openWhatsApp(String number) {
    String whatsAppMessage = "Hello!";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(i);
   }
```

Call above function and pass number, by which by want to open chat in Whatsapp messenger.

Hope it will work for you. :)

Comment: There is unused String whatsAppMessage.